# Unable to color Japan and North Korea in a d3 world map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I made a world map using d3 and I'm trying to color certain countries by using their id in css. This worked for all countries except Japan and North Korea. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fbzdn356/2/).

```
d3.json("world.json",function(error,world){

    if (error) return console.error(error);
    console.log(world)
    var subunits = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.subunits);


    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .scale((width - 1) / 2 / Math.PI);

    var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection); 


    svg.selectAll(".subunits")
        .data(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.subunits).features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", function(d) { console.log(d.id) ;return "subunit " + d.id; })
        .attr("id", function(d){ 
            var str=String(d.properties.name);
            if(str.replace(/[\s \.]/g, '').localeCompare("KoreanDMZ(north)")==0){
                console.log("it worked")
                return "Northkorea"
            }
            else
                return d.properties.name.replace(/[\s \.]/g, '');})
        .attr("d", path); 

    svg.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.mesh(world, world.objects.subunits, function(a, b) { return a !== b && !(a.id==="RUA"&&b.id==="RUE") }))
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("class", "subunit-boundary");


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS code is using country name to identify Japan (#Japan). The JSON data is using country name to identify some of the small islands (#Japan) but is using island names to identify some of the large islands (#Hokkaido, #Honshu, #Kyushu, etc). Thus, the large islands are not getting colored.

Your CSS code is missing identifiers for North and South Korea. The JSON data is using #Korea to identify South Korea and #DemRepKorea to identify North Korea. Thus, North and South Korea are not getting colored.

Comment: Thanks for the help.